# convert browser cookies and use in cURL crawls

Tags: php, curl, cookies

First of all, the purpose of this is to spider one of our signed-in applications and get data about jobs run which I may not be able to get any other way.

I can log in via a browser, and also can inspect my cookies; how would I then take that (in a timely manner) and add that information to a cURL call so that I can use PHP to parse the return page (and links)?

Answer (score 0):

cURL can read cookies from a Netscape cookie format file.

Since you can inspect the cookies, use this [Netscape format cookie file generator](http://crdx.org/misc/cookies/) to convert them to a file.

Then use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'file.txt');` so cURL will read the cookies from there where file.txt is the file you saved the cookies to.